# Getting Started With Script

Tags: transactions, script, bitcoin-qt-setup

I would like to manually write a few locking and unlocking scripts to get a deeper feel for that part of the network.  What is the simplest step-by-step set of instructions to set up everything needed to use Script in Windows, on regtest or some other testnet?  Is it possible to do this in Bitcoin-qt, or is working in the command-line a necessity?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [btcdeb](https://github.com/kallewoof/btcdeb) from kallewoof. It's a set of tools used to construct or debug bitcoin script.

Answer (score 0):

There is astoundingly very few information on script and "getting started" on the net, though one can find a lot of scripts. When you want to assemble a script, just to play around with its features and implications, it gets quickly very difficult.
I had answered a similiar question [here in detail](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/74753/htlc-hash-time-lock-contract-using-bitcoin-qt/74953#74953), to show first steps and how to go.

I am generally using unixoide type systems, so I am not 100% sure on Windows. But if you have a (regtest) daemon running, using the command line and sending it some commands should do the trick.

Basically there are 5 steps:

1. prepare addresses & balances
2. create a tx
3. sign the tx
4. adjust the scriptsig
5. send the tx

The most critical part is in step 4, where you need to play with length of the script - and probably a lot of trial and error :-) Good luck!